# Вывод связанных таблиц в GridView YII2

Tags: yii2, вывод, crud

Всем привет) Есть 3 таблицы в бд - **S_QUIZ_TOPIC**, **S_QUIZ_QUESTION**, **S_QUIZ_TQ**.

Таблица хранящая название тем **S_QUIZ_TOPIC** с полями

```
integer $ID_REC
string $NAME_TOPIC
integer $RANDOM
integer $MAX_TIME
string $DT_UP
integer $STATUS
```

Таблица хранящая вопросы **S_QUIZ_QUESTION** с полями

```
integer $ID_REC
string $NAME_QUEST
string $TEXT_QUEST
string $MSG_QUEST
integer $RANDOM
string $DT_UP
integer $STATUS
```

И связывающая эти 2 таблицы **S_QUIZ_TQ**

```
integer $ID_REC
integer $ID_TOPIC
integer $ID_QUESTION
string $DT_UP
integer $STATUS
```

Между этими таблицами есть связи:

Модель **SQuizTopic**

```
 public function getSQUIZTQs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SQUIZTQ::className(), ['ID_TOPIC' => 'ID_REC']);
    }
```

Модель **SQuizQuestion**

```
 public function getSQUIZTQs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SQUIZTQ::className(), ['ID_QUESTION' => 'ID_REC']);
    }
```

Модель **SQuizTQ**

```
public function getIDQUESTION()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(SQuizQuestion::className(), ['ID_REC' => 'ID_QUESTION']);
    }

    public function getIDTOPIC()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(SQuizTopic::className(), ['ID_REC' => 'ID_TOPIC']);
    }
```

Как мне в представлении, сгенерированным в CRUD и принадлежащем таблице **S_QUIZ_TOPIC** вывести поле **$NAME_QUEST**, которое принадлежит таблице **S_QUIZ_QUESTION** ? Подскажите пожалуйста, а то ничего не получается =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я это делал для представления "view", так что в контроллере SQuizTopic пишем:

```
public function actionView($id)
    {
        $searchModel = new SQuizQuestionSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }
```

И в самом "view":

```
<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            [
                    'attribute' => 'NAME_QUEST',
                    'label' => 'Список всех вопросов',
                ],
        ],
    ]); ?>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?></div>
```

Comment: И что разве так заработало ?

Comment: @madfan41k Да, заработало